# compute $(\sqrt 3 + i)^{14} + ( \sqrt 3 - i)^{14}$

Tags: complex-numbers

I want to compute $(\sqrt 3 + i)^{14}  + ( \sqrt 3 - i)^{14}$.

---

**My attempts:** I was thinking about De Moivre's theorem

$$(\cos\theta  + i \sin\theta)^n=  \cos(n\theta)  +  i \sin(n\theta)$$

but I don't know how it can be applied here. Any hints/solution  will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Write $\sqrt{3}\pm i$ in the form $r(\cos\theta\pm i\sin\theta)$ and then apply de Movire's theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right but you have have to express it in exponential (polar) form, 
$$\sqrt{3} + i = 2 e^{i \frac{\pi}{6}}$$
and
$$\sqrt{3} - i = 2 e^{-i \frac{\pi}{6}}$$
So that
$$(\sqrt{3} + i)^{14} = 2^{14} e^{i \frac{14\pi}{6}}$$
and
$$(\sqrt{3} - i)^{14} = 2^{14} e^{-i \frac{14\pi}{6}}$$
Since $(\sqrt{3} + i)^{14}$ and $(\sqrt{3} - i)^{14}$ are complex conjugates, then
$(\sqrt{3} + i)^{14} + (\sqrt{3} - i)^{14} = 2\Re\{(\sqrt{3} + i)^{14}\} = 2(2^{14} \cdot\Re\{e^{i \frac{\pi}{6}}\}) $

Comment: thanks @taritgoswami

Comment: Note that $(2a)^{14} = 2^{14}  a^{14} \neq 2 a^{14} $.

Comment: thanks @MathLover

Answer (score 2):

HINT:  $\sqrt{3}+i=2(\cos(\pi/6)+i\sin(\pi/6))$, $\sqrt{3}-i=2(\cos(-\pi/6)+i\sin(-\pi/6))$.